Tournament of Towns Problem about determining coefficients of a Polynomial

Baron Munchhausen was told that some polynomial $P(x) = a_nx^n + . . . + a_1x + a_0$ is such that $P(x) + P(−x)$ has exactly 45 distinct real
roots. Baron doesn’t know the value of $n$. Nevertheless he claims that
he can determine one of the coefficients $a_n, . . . , a_1, a_0$
(indicating its position and value). Isn’t Baron mistaken?

My solution:
Let $x=\alpha$ be a root of $P(x) + P(-x)=0$. It follows, by symmetry, that $x=-\alpha$ is also a root. We have obtained a pairing across roots, that shows that the number of distinct real roots must be even. But it is odd, and thus $x=0$ is a root. Thus $P(0) + P(0) = 0 \implies 2a_0 = 0 \implies a_0 = 0$. Baron is not mistaken! Is this solution correct?
The reason I am unsure, is that the question mentioned 45 distinct real roots, but there were no mention of if there were any additional repeated roots.

I think the solution with $P(\alpha)+P(-\alpha)=0 \iff P(-\alpha)+P(\alpha)=0$, so if there are an odd number of such $\alpha$ then one of them is $0$ and thus $a_0=0$ is satisfactory.  I do not see how an $\alpha$ possibly being a repeated root of $P(\alpha)+P(-\alpha)=0$ would affect the argument, as the same would then be true of $-\alpha$.

Wait, how does $\alpha$ being a repeated root imply $-\alpha$ is a repeated root.

$P(x)+P(-x)$ is a polynomial with only even powers of $x$, so any positive root and the paired negative root have the same degree since their squares are equal.

Continuing on Henry's argument: as there are $45$ different real roots, one of them should be zero, meaning that $a_0=0$.
